# Grafico de Barra con Google Chart, PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-chart-api

tengo el siguiente arreglo emanado de una consulta en Mysql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito crear un grafico en google charts de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito por favor, una orientacion tecnica de como configurar google chart, en PHP, para que muestre el grafico de esa manera con los datos extraidos de la consulta.
Gracias

el codigo que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['municipio'. 'estatus', 'SUBTOTAL'],
          <?php
               while ($filas = $res->fetch_assoc()){
               echo "['".$row['municipio']."','".$row['estatus']."', ".$row['SUBTOTAL']."],";
               //echo "['".$filas["estatus"]."', ".$filas["SUBTOTAL"]."],";     

                    }
          ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Estatus de Reportes por Municipios',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Este Script:

```
<?php 
  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbUsername = 'root';
  $dbPassword = '';
  $dbName = 'redes';

  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  $query3 ="SELECT municipio, servicio_periferico.servicio as SERVICIO, estatus, count(estatus) as SUBTOTAL FROM reporte, estatus,servicio_periferico, municipio 
        WHERE 
        idestatus=estatus.id AND
        id_serv_perf=servicio_periferico.id AND 
        idmunicipio = municipio.id AND
        MONTH(fecha_recibido) = month(curdate()) and
        year(fecha_recibido) = year(curdate())
        GROUP by municipio, estatus
$res = mysqli_query($db,$query3);
?>
<html>
<body>
          <?php
           if($res->num_rows > 0){
             while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo "['".$row['municipio']."','".$row['estatus']."', ".$row['SUBTOTAL']."],";
                echo "</br>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

me arroja el siguiente arreglo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es armar ese arreglo de tal forma, utilizando google chart, que me permita obtener una grafica de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué has intentado y dónde tienes problemas? Hay ejemplos detallados para hacerlo en https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart. Lo único que necesitas es rellenar el valor de data para el gráfico recorriendo el resultado de tu consulta con un bucle en PHP.

Comment: Hola, he tomado el ejemplo de trae google charts para tal fin pero solo lo hace para dos(02) series, en mi caso necesito configurarlo para que tome y grafique al menos tres(03)

Comment: he utilizado la siguiente rutina pero no muestra nada:

Comment: HGarcia añade tu código para ver dónde puede estar el problema, con el resultado obtenido y el esperado para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. En el ejemplo enlace tienes un ejemplo de material column chart que gráfica 4 datos con 3 columnas cada uno.

Comment: ¿como hago para colocar codigo en este comentario?

Comment: Edita la pregunta

Comment: No se ve muy bien el codigo Carmen, podrias decirme cua es el formato?

Comment: Seleccionas y le das a las llaves para formatear código. En data la separación entre municipio y estatus debe ser una coma, no un punto.

Comment: estan separadas por una coma

Comment: En la definición de los campos ['municipio'. 'estatus', 'SUBTOTAL'], y sobra la coma del final en el último recorrido del bucle, la añades siempre en el echo al recorrer

Comment: ok, disculpa ya lo vi, pero igual no muestra nada

Comment: Y por último tu variable  dónde recorres los resultados es $filas y en el echo llamas a $row

Comment: ok, cambie $filas, ejecute y me arrojo lo siguiente: "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type"

Comment: municipio y estatus son de tipo "varchar" y SUBTOTAL es "numerico"

Comment: En realidad sólo necesitas mostrar municipio y estatus para obtener el gráfico de la imagen, el primer campo es puede ser varchar porque va a ser el nombre, y el los demás deben ser numéricos para poder graficarlos. Para que los agrupe hay que convertir el bucle en tres áreas en lugar de 6. Pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: si pero tambien necesito que los agrupe por "SERVICIOS", osea que muestre los estatus (ACTIVOS, RESUELTOS) por "SERVICIOS"  y por municipio

Answer (score 0):

Hay que agrupar los datos al recorrerlos para que los muestre como quieres, agrupados por municipio.

Considerando que obtienes los resultados ordenados por municipio y en cada municipio primero el activo y después el resuelto, construyes los datos para mostrar municipio - activo - resuelto en cada caso del eje x.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['municipio', 'activo', 'resuelto']
              <?php
                  $municipio ="";
                   while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                   if ($municipio != $row['municipio']) {
                       //si es un nuevo municipio mostramos municipio y el activo
                       $municipio = $row['municipio'];
                       echo ",['".$row['municipio']."',".$row['SUBTOTAL'].";
                    } else {
                       // mostramos el valor del resuelto
                       echo ",".$row['SUBTOTAL']."]";
                     }

                        }
              ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'Estatus de Reportes por Municipios',
              is3D: true,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }

        </script>
```

La otra opción sería modificar cómo obtienes los resultados para que se adapten al gráfico. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola Carmen, si puedes darme una direccion de correo, me gustaria enviarte la estructura de la BD y el codigo completo para que lo analices y ver si puedes ayudarme, gracias

Comment: @HGarcia la ayuda es a través de este medio, para eso existe la plataforma

Comment: @HGarcia vista tu query, podrías hacer la consulta con un select para agrupar por municipios y dos selects internos para sacar el count de activos y resueltos, algo del tipo SELECT municipio, (SELECT count(estatus) FROM status WHERE *aqui tus condiciones para municipio=municipio.id y status activo*) AS SUBTOTAL_ACTIVO, (SELECT count(estatus) FROM status WHERE *aqui tus condiciones para municipio=municipio.id y status resuelto*) AS SUBTOTAL_RESUELTO FROM reporte, estatus,servicio_periferico, municipio 
        WHERE *tus condiciones para seleccionar los municipios a mostrar*.